# Como executar uma busca em um array até que uma condição seja atendida?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

Eu tenho um array de usuários vindos de um banco de dados firebase, eu capturo esse array e executo um map para capturar algumas informações, por ex: montar um array de cpf, telefone...Esse array de cpf por exemplo eu usarei para comparar com o cpf que o cliente insere no momento do cadastro dele, para bloquear o cadastro com um cpf já existente. Tentei utilizar o for para fazer isso, porém o for percorre toda a lista, quando ele chega a condição de igualdade (encontra o cpf repetido) ele retorna um true, porém como ele continua executando a lista ele retorna um false logo em seguida, pois os demais cpfs são diferentes desse.

Gostaria de saber como eu posso executar essa comparação até que a condição seja atendida? Por exemplo, quero fazer o for até que o cpf repetido seja encontrado, me retorna o true e eu trato o resto, o que fiz até agora foi.

Aqui eu faço o map retornando email, cpf, telefone, nome...

```
  this.pacientesSubscription = this.pacienteProvider.buscarPacientes().subscribe(data => {
  this.cpfsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.cpfSolicitante;
  })

  this.rgsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.rgSolicitante;
  })

  this.emailsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.emailSolicitante;
  })

  this.telefonesCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.telefone;
  })

  this.nomesCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.nomeSolicitante;
  })
})
```

Depois aqui eu tento fazer o comparativo. Que nada mais é que, entre na lista de nomes, se o nome na posição i for igual ao digitado, me retorne um true na variável nomeRepetido. Porém ele continua percorrendo a lista e chega até o nomeRepetido = false. Porque os demais nomes da lista são diferentes.

```
consultaNome(){
for(let i = 0; i < this.nomesCadastrados.length; i++){
  if(this.nomesCadastrados[i] === this.paciente.nomeSolicitante){
    this.nomeRepetido = true;
    alert('Já existe um cadastro com este nome na nossa plataforma, por favor corrija este campo');
  } else {
    this.nomeRepetido = false;
  }
  console.log(this.nomeRepetido);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade de estar sempre a definir o nomeRepetido a false, se o definires antes a false, só o precisas de alterar 1x..

Quando a condição for verdadeira podes colocar o `i = this.nomesCadastrados.length`

Comment: Obrigado cara, a sua resposta me ajudou a resolver aqui, fiz como você falou.

Answer (score 0):

Segue o exemplo de como ficou o resultado final, inclui também mais um nó de dados para comparação:

```
consultaNome(){
this.nomeRepetido = false;
for(let i = 0; i < this.nomesCadastrados.length; i++){
  if(this.nomesCadastrados[i] === this.paciente.nomeSolicitante){
    this.nomeRepetido = true;
    i = this.nomesCadastrados.length;
    alert('Já existe um cadastro com este nome na nossa plataforma, por favor corrija este campo');
  }
  console.log(this.nomeRepetido);
}

for(let i = 0; i < this.nomesProfissionaisCadastrados.length; i++){
  if(this.nomesProfissionaisCadastrados[i] === this.paciente.nomeSolicitante){
    this.nomeRepetido = true;
    i = this.nomesCadastrados.length;
    alert('Já existe um cadastro com este nome na nossa plataforma, por favor corrija este campo');
  }
  console.log(this.nomeRepetido);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra alternativa é que você pode ao invés de utilizar um **for** simples, utilizar um método mais avançado como o [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), que retorna um boolean conforme o retorno de uma condição testada por ele:

```
public nomesCadastrados = [];
public repetido: boolean;
public valorDigitadoPeloUsuario: any;

this.pacientesSubscription = this.pacienteProvider.buscarPacientes().subscribe(data => {
  this.cpfsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.cpfSolicitante;
  })

  this.rgsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.rgSolicitante;
  })

  this.emailsCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.emailSolicitante;
  })

  this.telefonesCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.telefone;
  })

  this.nomesCadastrados = data.map(result => {
    return result.nomeSolicitante;
  })
})

consultaNome(){
  this.nomesCadastrados.filter((elemento: any) => {
    if(elemento == this.valorDigitadoPeloUsuario) {
      this.repetido == true;
      alert('Já existe um cadastro com este nome na nossa plataforma, por favor corrija este campo');
    }
  })
}
```